# What can cause a multi-column Unique index in MS Access not to work?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table tblPerson with indexes defined as shown below. The index UniquePerson is intended prevent duplicate records being created but is not working - I **can** create duplicate records.

Table indexes:

[image: Image of table indexes]

The fields in the UniquePerson Index are defined as follows:

- **GenID**: Text(50), Not required, not unique, default value "", caption FH ID
- **GroupID**: Long Integer(Lookup on another table), Required, No default
  value, validation rule "Is Not Null"
- **Surname**: Text(255), Not required, not unique, default value ""
- **GivenNames**: Text(255), Not required, not unique, default value ""

There's a validation rule on the table which checks that at least one of Surname and GivenNames is specified:

```
Trim$([Surname] & [GivenNames] & " ")<>""
```

Also, both Surname and GivenNames are stripped of leading, trailing and multiple spaces before being added to the database. GenID can contain all sorts of spaces, but that isn't the issue in the duplicates I've found.

I *believe* the way the fields are defined should mean that the index shouldn't fall foul of the problem of some of the fields being null... So what else can cause the necessary uniqueness not to be enforced?

(I've eliminated database corruption as a possible cause by recreating a clean database that still has the problem).

Updated to include an example of duplicates:

[image: duplicates]

Note: GenID is displayed to users as FH ID (long story, don't ask)

Comment: Can you give us an example of the non-unique rows that you believe are violating your rules?

Comment: @MattGibson done. I've also added a note about the handling of spaces in the text fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unique index contains Nullable columns (i.e., fields where `Required` = `No`) and that is what is causing the confusion. If you create a unique index that includes the fields [Surname] and [GivenNames] then the database engine will ensure that no two records have the same *actual values* in both of those fields. In other words, an insert or update will fail if the engine can find some other existing record that satisfies the condition

```sql
[Lastname] = newrecord.[Lastname] AND [GivenNames] = newrecord.[GivenNames]
```

If either `newrecord.[Lastname]` or `newrecord.[GivenNames]` is NULL then no existing record will ever match those criteria, ***even another existing record with NULL values***, because NULL is never equal to anything, not even another NULL.

One workaround for this would be to ensure that the currently Nullable fields have `Allow Zero Length` set to `Yes`, update all NULL values to zero-length strings, and then set the `Required` property of those fields to `Yes`.

Comment: So, the key thing is not that no actual data anywhere in the fields forming the index is Null (which it isn't in my scenario because the data entry form UI prevents it), but that there's no possibility that it might be Null? Now I need to work out how to fix the dozens of data files out there without losing data for my users...